Is it legal and ethical to copy someone else's GitHub Gist into my own repository?
I'm writing a Markdown file for personal documentation and learning purposes. I found a useful piece of code in a public GitHub Gist, but also I changed it a bit to fit my needs. I'd like to include this in my Markdown file, but I'm concerned about the legal and ethical considerations involved. Is it legally and ethically acceptable to do so?  If it’s allowed, what is the best way to give proper attribution to the original author?
Consider, my repository does not include any project programming language—it's just a personal Markdown document.

I know a gist isn't a "project" per se, but assuming it's significant enough to be copyrightable at all the same answers apply. If it's not significant enough to be copyrightable, it's probably not worth copying.

If it's just for your own personal reference, i.e. if you are not distributing it, then the issue becomes almost moot as far as software licenses are concerned. Technically you are infringing a copyright whenever you make a copy without authorisation, however there there are lots of legal exceptions allowed in most jurisdictions for this kind of personal copying for reference (sans distribution, of course). But this becomes more of a https://law.stackexchange.com/ question at that point, one which I believe has been asked and answered lots of times before.
